# Excel 2010 copy paste of multiple rows

Tags: excel

For example I have this table with two columns (**Category** and **ID**)... I need to split the categories based on the number of IDs. I have provided a sample table below. Now this may seem easy but I'm working on 15,000+ lines here (30,000+ lines after splitting) and doing it manually would really take too much of my time. If you know any copy-paste tricks or formulas that may help me with this, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

By the way I'm using MS Excel 2010.

Note: Some IDs are up to 2 to 10 lines...

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a macro to insert a new row before each cell in column A that has the text "Category"?

Comment: If that would work, yes. But sometimes the IDs are not just 2. Some categories have 2-10 IDs.. which means that category has to be split up to 10 times depending on the number of IDs

Comment: No, i'm not trying to group them. I'm trying to SPLIT them... please see example above

Comment: Assuming Category contains unique records?

Answer (score 1):

You might try Copy your data and Paste Special Unformatted Text into Word. Replace ^pC with ^tC then ^p with ^tx^t. Select All, Insert Table, Convert Text to Table with Number of Columns: 2. Copy back in to Excel and replace `x` with nothing. Select that column, Go To Special, Blanks and type `=`, `Up`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Sub Main()
    Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Key2:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    rowB = 2: ctr2 = 2
    For ctr1 = 1 To Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
        arrData = Split(Range("B" & rowB), vbLf)
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrData)
            Sheets(2).Range("A" & ctr2) = Sheets(1).Range("A" & ctr1 + 1).Value
            Sheets(2).Range("B" & ctr2) = arrData(i)
            ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
        Next i
        rowB = rowB + 1
    Next ctr1
End Sub
```

Assumptions

- Category would be unique
- The IDs are separated by line feeds